# ListBox.SelectedItem selected wrong row

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I create `ListBox`, wich rows can be editable:

```
 <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lbKeys" BorderBrush="Gray" 
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=Templates}"                                         
                                     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                                     Focusable="True"

                                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=lbStyle}">



                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" Background="WhiteSmoke"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid Name="grEditRow">
                                    <TextBox x:Name="tblbRow" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

                                               TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="2"
                                                       Background="Transparent"
                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"

                                               />

                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

But, when i select row for edit (and i can do it)- i want to delete this row by clicking to button:

```
<Button x:Name="btDelTemplate"  Click="btDelTemplate_Click"  Height="22" Width="22"
                                                    ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
                                    ToolTip="{lang:Link LocalePath=RemoveTemplate,DesignValue='Remove row'}"
                                    >
</Button>
```

And event handler of it:

```
if(lbKeys.SelectedItem!=null)
    RemoveItem(lbKeys.SelectedItem as Row);
```

But, selected item often is wrong! As i understand- if i select item by clicking at left border of row- it works well, but when click at textbox inside row- selected item is wrong.

How to fix it? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a workaround.
Here the code:

XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lbKeys" BorderBrush="Gray" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding  Templates}"                                         
                                     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                                     Focusable="True"

                                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=lbStyle}">



                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" Background="WhiteSmoke"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

                                <TextBox x:Name="tblbRow" Text="{Binding Text,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
 Tag="{Binding}"
 GotFocus="tblbRow_GotFocus"                                                       

                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="2"
                                                   Background="Transparent"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"

                                           />


                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Key lines:

```
Tag="{Binding}"
GotFocus="tblbRow_GotFocus"
```

C# handlers:

```
private void tblbRow_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        lbKeys.SelectedItem = textBox.Tag;                       
   }





private void btDelTemplate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            foreach (var item in lbKeys.Cast<Row>())
            {
                if (item.Template.Id == (lbKeys.SelectedItem as Row).Template.Id)
                {
                    _viewModel.RemoveTemplate(item);
                    break;
                }
            }               
            DataContext = _viewModel;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a handler for GotFocus of the TextBox and change SelectedItem in that programmatically.

--------- Update ----------

```
private void tblbRow_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbKeys.SelectedItem = (sender as TextBox).DataContext as Row;                      
    }
```

and you should write some code for Row class to let its objects be comparable:

```
public class Row
    {
        public Row() { }
        private string _text;
        public String Text
        {
            get
            {               
                return _text;
            }
        set
        {
            _text = value;                
        }
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _text;
    }
    public bool Equals(Row r)
    {
        return r._text == _text;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object r)
    {
        Row row = r as Row;
        return row != null && row._text == _text;
    }
}
```

Comment: but how do i get object of selected item? for example, i set lb.SelectedItem=sender as TextBox; (if it possible). But the type of SelectedItem (row) is not a text, but Row (wich contains text and other info).
So, if i have 2 rows with 2 idencial text- how i can select item?

Comment: Write (sender as TextBox).DataContext as YourClass , YourClass will be the type of binded items which you set as ItemsSource

Comment: i select my own answer, because it works for me. Thank you for your answer!